# How can write below script in magento 2

Tags: magento2, validation, system-config

How can i write below script in magento 2

```
class NameSpace_Notification_Model_App extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
 {

   public function save(){ } 

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to override that class Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data and save method?

Answer (score 1):

in magento 2 you can write code

```
 <?php
    namespace NameSpace_Notification_Model;

    class App extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config
    {


    public function save(){ } 

    }
```

> *Note::your **__construct** must be same with **\Magento\Config\Model\Config __construct***

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this,

```
namespace {NameSpace}\{Module}\Model;

class App extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config
{
   public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface $config,
            \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
            \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure $configStructure,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
            \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Loader $configLoader,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($config, $eventManager, $configStructure, $transactionFactory, $configLoader, $configValueFactory, $storeManager, $data);
    }

    public function save(){ } 
...
}
```

and in your `etc/di.xml` file you have to override

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Config\Model\Config" type="{NameSpace}\{ModuleName}\Model\{Your_Model_File}" />
</config>
```

You can also refer [this](http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/) url.

After that you have to recompile.